# Axios Error message: 'Request failed with status code 404'

Tags: reactjs, api, express, http-status-code-404, mern

I am working on a mern app and I triedto fetch the restaurants from the database when the user types a restaurant name in the search bar. However on making an axios get request, the console shows this error " Request failed with status code 404". Here is the react code for that:

```
const SearchBar = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  // Function to fetch search results from backend API
  const fetchSearchResults = async (query) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/delivery/search?searchString=${query}`);
      setSearchResults(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  // Function to handle search input change
  const handleSearchInputChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setSearchTerm(value);
  };

  // Function to handle search form submission
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // window.location.href = `/delivery/search`;
    fetchSearchResults(searchTerm);
  };
```

This is the backend code to handle the api request and fetch data from the database

```
const router = express.router();
router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
try {
    console.log("running");
    const { searchString } = req.query.searchString;

    await validateSearchString(searchString);
    console.log("running");
    const restaurants = await RestaurantModel.find({
      name: { $regex: searchString, $options: "i" },
    });

    if (!restaurants.length === 0) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ error: `No restaurant matched with ${searchString}` });
    }

    return res.json({ restaurants });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

Here I put a console.log which does not run in console. So I'm assuming that this code does not run at all when the user searches a restaurant and thus it gives back an axios error.
The search bar is displayed on the url 'http://localhost:3000/delivery'
[this is the screenshot of the network request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM2Fl.png)
Can you please help me resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of of the network request details in browser developer tools? What is the url there? Is it the url of your backend?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I have included the screenshot now. And the url for the backend is /delivery/search and same is the axios request url